# Getting specific JSON values in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a small app and in one of the buttons it retrieves a JSON file from online and it prints the result, but how can I utilize the JSON result, for example, rather than having to print to print an entire JSON, I want to print just one of the values, such as JSON["data"][1].

Here is my code:

```
  @IBAction func approveuser(sender: AnyObject) {
        let postEndpoint: String = "https://example.com/example.json"
        let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let postParams : [String: AnyObject] = ["UUID": UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString, "requested": place]
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //can be changed.
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        do {
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postParams, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
            print(postParams)
        } catch {
            print("bad things happened")
        }
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
                realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    print("Not a 200 response")
                    return
            }



            // Read the JSON
            if let postString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
                print("POST: " + postString)
                //
            }
        }).resume()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON values are retrieved via their keys. Whether it be arrays or just objects. A json can contain multiple other json objects or json arrays. You can use your own custom class to retrieve values. To implement this you can look at this [code](https://bitbucket.org/mayankb03/demo/src/0d81cd12c7350a6291d96588adc3de9e97f57de2/EfficientJSONDemo/?at=EfficientJSON) to understand.
Or in iOS you can just use SwiftyJSON to retrieve values in less brainstorming on your part. For example using SwiftyJSON you can do as -

```
{  {"user": {
      "name": "..."
       }
    },
    {"address": "..."
   }
}
```

For this you can code as:

```
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
  //Now you got your value
}
```

Where 'dataFromNetworking' is your NSData read from the URL and contains json like above.

Like this, you can just retrieve value from the json. To understand more about SwiftyJSON go to this [link](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

Comment: When I try this code it give me the error 'Use of unidentified resolver "JSON" '

Comment: have you included pod? It won't work till you don't integrate SwiftyJSON using cocoapods or carthage.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example of retreiving data from json:

json format:

```
[
  {
    "person": {
      "name": "Rob",
      "age": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    "person": {
      "name": "joe",
      "age": "73"
    }
  }
]
```

related code:

```
var json: Array!    
do {
      json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? Array
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }

    if let item = json[0] as? [String: AnyObject] {
      if let person = item["person"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let age = person["age"] as? Int {
          print("Rob's age is \(age)")
        }
      }
    }
```